# swi-prolog Combination of lists whose heads are unique

Tags: list, prolog, combinations

I tried to modify this combination predicate:

```
comb(+PairCount,+List,-Combination)/3

comb(0,_,[]).
comb(N,[X|T],[X|Comb]):-N>0,N1 is N-1,comb(N1,T,Comb).
comb(N,[_|T],Comb):-N>0,comb(N,T,Comb).
```

To make it include only lists with *unique heads* so that when I run this:

```
?- comb(2, [[1,2],[1,3],[2,4]], L].
```

I should get:

```
L= [[1,2],[2,4]];
L= [[1,3],[2,4]].
```

I tried something like this but since I can't get current CombinationList, I can't restrict it by this way:

```
comb(0,_,[]).
comb(N,[X|T],[X|Comb]):-
    N>0, N1 is N-1,
    + X = [H|_],
    + % H is not head of any of the current CombinationList's items,
    comb(N1,T,Comb).
comb(N,[_|T],Comb):-
    N>0,
    comb(N,T,Comb).
```

I may be thinking unnecessarily procedural, but here it is. It would be also fine if you propose a whole different solution instead of modifying my given predicate.

Comment: What you have is close. In your second clause, just add, after `comb(N1, T, Comb)`, the call `\+ memberchk([H|_], Comb)`.

Comment: @lurker: What about a pure solution?